# Notation for a function from all members of a tuple minus one.

Tags: notation

Is there any compact, mainstream notation for a function from all members of a tuple minus one? What I have in mind is

$f\left(a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\right)$ (except for $a_{i}$) $=a_{i}$

Comment: Is it a set, or a tuple?

Comment: A tuple, of course. Editing. Thanks.

Comment: I have seen $f(a_1,\dots,\hat a_i,\dots,a_n)$, though of course it must be explained when it’s introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean an ordered tuple, then a common notation for
$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i-1},a_{i+1},\ldots,a_n)$$
is
$$(a_1,a_2,\ldots,\widehat{a_i},\ldots,a_n).$$
But it is usually specified in text what it means the first time it is used.

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I usually see this denoted $f(a_1,\ldots,\hat a_i,\ldots,a_n)$, with the $\hat\cdot$ sumbol used to denote exclusion.